# If $S_n^f(x_0)-S_n^g(x_0)\to 0$, then $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f, g\colon [-\pi, \pi]\to\mathbf{R}$ be continuous $2\pi$-periodic functions and let $S_n^f$ and $S_n^g$ be their corresponding partial Fourier sums.
I need to show that if $S_n^f(x_0)-S_n^g(x_0)\to 0$, then $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$. The hint to this problem was Fejèr's theorem, but I'm not sure how to proceed. To me this appears to be some kind of opposite result to the Riemann localization principle.

Comment: As as first step, notice that $S_n$ is linear, so this is equivalent so the simpler statement $S_n^f(x_0) \to 0 \implies f(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: Right.. So if $S_n^f(x_0)\to 0$, then the arithmetic means of $S_n^f(x_0)$ also converge to $0$. By Fejèr's theorem we know that the arithmetic means converge to $f(x_0)$ at $x_0$ since $f$ is continuous. By uniqueness of limits we must have $f(x_0)=0$. Am I correct?

Comment: If that is what your Fejer's theorem states, this seems correct to me. By arithmetic mean you mean $\frac{1}{n} S_n$?

Comment: Yes, by arithmetic means I mean the averages $\sigma_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n S_k$.